# Unity Shader Vertex Format in Surface Shader

Tags: shader, unity-game-engine, surface, vertex

I am attempting to use the vertex data in a surface shader to get an angle.  I have the camera centered at 0,0.  In what coordinate system is v.vertex in the vertex function?

```
#pragma surface surf Lambert vertex:vert nolightmap 

void vert (inout appdata_full v, out Input o) 
    {
        o.svc =(1-(_vc*v.vertex.z)/sqrt(pow(v.vertex.x,2) + pow(v.vertex.y,2) + pow(v.vertex.z,2)))/sqrt( 1 - _vc  * _vc);
    }
```

I thought it would be the world coordinate system, but I get different results for objects that are rotated in unity when compared to objects that are rotated in 3DS Max ahead of time to look the same vertex wise.  What data am I actually recieving with v.vertex.xyz?

Comment: You should use multiplication instead of powers, and inverse square root instead of dividing by square roots.  Also, GPUs are parallel and offer swizzling.  Clean that up to v.vertex.xyz * v.vertex.xyz.

Answer (score 1):

Object/Model/Local space.  The only case where this will not be completely true, is for batched meshes.  Batching puts all relevant meshes into the same space, which happens to be the same as world space.